# Can google recaptcha site and secret keys be created using api

Tags: recaptcha

Checked for apis in google for creating the site and secret keys which is required to form the recaptcha. Couldn't find one. Is there any way this can be done

Answer (score 1):

i dont think its possible. the process to create new site and secret key is manual. i tried searching their api, but cant find anything which lets u automate or create site keys for any domain using api.

IN SHORT: NO

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but the only current answer is no longer correct.

To create a key, you can make a post call to `https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/keys` where the project is the name of your project.

The post data might look something like this:

```
{
  "displayName": "Example",
  "webSettings": {
    "allowedDomains": [
      "example.com"
    ],
    "integrationType": 1
  }
}
```

See more information here: https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.keys/create

You also have the option to use the libraries provided by Google: https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/samples/recaptcha-enterprise-update-site-key